# Bi-weekly Task Reporting

Tags: ms-project

I'm trying to get a report that shows the tasks due this week and next. I haven't been able to figure a way to do it. How can I run a report showing just the next 2 weeks tasks and their status?

Comment: Both of the replies below relate to viewing the data in a filtered view.  Are you looking for a printed report?  A dashboard report?  In both circumstances, the answer is based upon what version (2007, 2010, 2013) you are running.  Give us more information and we'll try to be more helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Exact details depend on the version of project you're using.  I'm using project 2010

On the view menu, choose filter, then "new filter" - enter in the window you want to see  and filter the project to just those dates.

Comment: For MS-P 2013 it is *View*->Filter->Date Range